# Select multiple properties where one of the properties must be unique in a pipeline

Tags: arrays, powershell, filtering, unique, pipeline

Using `Select-Object`, you can select the first of multiple occurences of an object using `-Unique`. You can also select only some properties to be retained. But what if I want to check for the uniqueness of only one property, filter out all non-unique ones and not just leave one of them, and allow the other properties to pass through unchanged? Specifically, I have a list of `PSCustomObject`s where one property is a base name, and another is a shortened name generated automatically. I want to filter out elements where the short name occurs multiple times, but the base names of all items are all different. It seems `Select-Object` isn't a match for this task, but what is?

EDIT: To clarify - this should be the result:

```bsh
> $A = [PSCustomObject]@{A = 1; B = 2}, [PSCustomObject]@{A = 2; B = 2}, [PSCustomObject]@{A = 4; B = 1}
> $A

A B
- -
1 2
2 2
4 1

> $A | Mystery-Cmdlet "B"

A B
- -
4 1
```

Comment: Did you mean `Select-Object`? `Where-Object` doesn't have a `-Unique` switch

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Maybe `$A | Group-Object -Property B | Where-Object Count -eq 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group`?

Comment: You can use `$a[2]` to see rows and `$a.a` to see specific columns. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @NekoMusume ...no
why would it?

Comment: What is `Mystery-Cmdlet`? This can show you the specified output `$a[2]`

Comment: `Mystery-Cmdlet` is something that solves the problem in the question. I want to go through an array and throw out all elements if the value of its B property is found in any other element's B value.

Comment: @JosefZ yes, that solves it, although I'd use `ForEach-Object Group` instead, thanks. Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I have a list of `PSCustomObject`s…
>  I want to check for the uniqueness of only one property, filter out all non-unique ones and
>   not just leave one of them, and allow the other properties to pass
>   through unchanged…*

Let's rewrite above requirements in terms of PowerShell cmdlets:

```
$A = @'
A,B
1,2
2,2
4,1
5,4
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ','        # a list of PSCustomObjects

$A |
  Group-Object -Property B |               # check for the uniqueness,
    Where-Object Count -eq 1 |             # filter out all non-unique ones,
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group  # and pass through the rest unchanged
```

**Output**: `62219608.ps1`

> ```
> A B
> - -
> 4 1
> 5 4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to resolve it with code

```
$A = [PSCustomObject]@{A = 1; B = 2}, [PSCustomObject]@{A = 2; B = 2}, [PSCustomObject]@{A = 4; B = 1}

$A | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Count -NotePropertyValue init

for ($i=0; $i -lt $a.Length; $i++) {
$a[$i].Count = ($A.B | Where-Object {$_ -eq $a[$i].B}).Count
}

$a | Where-Object {$_.Count -eq 1}
```